# How to get all IndexOf instances of string in another string C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a huge string (pages of content) I would like to get all index of instances of a sub-string.

Example: How are **you** and where are **you**?

How do I get the Index of all **you** in the above sentence.

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use following exension. It uses [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms224423.aspx) in a loop with the overload which allows to pass the index you want to start the search. Loop until it returns `-1` and add the found indices to a collection:

```
public static IList<int> AllIndexOf(this string text, string str, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    IList<int> allIndexOf = new List<int>();
    int index = text.IndexOf(str, comparisonType);
    while(index != -1)
    {
        allIndexOf.Add(index);
        index = text.IndexOf(str, index + 1, comparisonType);
    }
    return allIndexOf;
}
```

You use it in this way:

```
string text = " How are you and where are you?";
var allIndexOf = text.AllIndexOf("you", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", allIndexOf));  // 9,27
```

The `StringComparison` allows to search in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: Nice answer, but it will fail with nested strings, e.g., if text = "nestednestednested" and str = "nestednested", then the method will return 1. It's enough to change `index + str.Length` to `index + 1` in the second line of the while loop.

Comment: @Xam: good catch, fixed it

Answer (score 5):

You can use IndexOf method [with startIndex parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) in cycle, and pass `last_match_index + 1` to it.

Something like:

```
int pos=-1, count=0;

while((pos=str.IndexOf("you",pos+1))!=-1)
{
   count++;
}
```

Comment: right answer, but a little example will be very helpful

Answer (score 5):

```
string input = "How are you and where are you?";
var indexes = Regex.Matches(input, "you").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: +0: this shows equivalent of "sql injection" for regular expressions - searching for something like `"foo."` will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov of course, if you are sure for *"you"* coming from user input..