# Get substring between indexes

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, loops

I need to get all substring between indexes for a given larger string

```
 string MyString="Hi Hello World 1 today is august 22 2022,Hello World 2 today is august 23 2022,Hello World 3 today is august 24 2022";
 string stringToFind = "today";
   List<int> positions = new List<int>();
    int pos = 0;
    while ((pos < MyString.Length) && (pos = MyString.IndexOf(stringToFind, pos)) != -1)
    {
        positions.Add(pos);
        pos += stringToFind.Length;
       
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences", positions.Count);
    foreach (var p in positions)
    {
       string amountString = MyString.Substring(p, p - 1);
       Console.WriteLine(amountString);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
```

I need to get the first substring as :today is august 22 2022
the second one as :today is august 23 2022  then today is august 24 2022
but When i try to get the substring using "substring" i'am getting an error.

```
 string amountString = MyString.Substring(p, p - 1);
```

Comment: What is the error? Let us know and we will be much better placed to answer! Give us an example of input and expected output too.

Comment: sample input string and expected output will help us to find better answer

Comment: Remember, the second parameter for Substring is the size (number of characters) of the substring to extract not the position where the substring ends or starts or whatever _p-1_ is

Comment: You can use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15993446/284240. I think your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993357/how-to-get-all-indexof-instances-of-string-in-another-string-c-sharp) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865419/indexof-for-multiple-results).

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output to show what you are trying to do. The second parameter to Substring i.e. p-1 does not look to be correct as it will be negative and hence give an error if p is zero and also generate another error if p is more than half the length of MyString.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you want to achieve, since your code is not working.

Comment: PS: I would change `pos += stringToFind.Length;` to `pos++;`. Then you will also find overlapping substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also might want to use `Regex` to do this. It's much simpler.

```
string MyString = "Hi Hello World 1 today is august 22 2022,Hello World 2 today is august 23 2022,Hello World 3 today is august 24 2022";
string stringToFind = "today";

List<int> positions =
    Regex
        .Matches(MyString, Regex.Escape(stringToFind))
        .Select(x => x.Index)
        .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences", positions.Count);

foreach (var p in positions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

That gives me:

```
3 occurrences
17
55
93
```

Comment: _" It's much simpler"_ I will never understand why someone thinks regex is simpler than anything else, but thats my personal opinion. In this case you might even be right. However, what if the substring is overlapping? Do you get all indexes anyway?

Comment: I agree, however my problem is that i need to get the value of the substrings not only the occurences.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - It is when you don't have to hand-write the pattern. Calling `.Matches(MyString, Regex.Escape(stringToFind))` is dead simple.

Comment: @nando99 - You start with the substring value - you know exactly what that is when you search for it.

Comment: @nando99: Maybe you want to list the words in what the substring was found, then you have to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string amountString = MyString.Substring(p, stringToFind.Length);
```

Comment: which will print n-times "today", but yes, this fixes the issue because `String.Substring`'s second parameter is the length.